# How to change search result page from 3 to 2 columns left in magento Go?

Tags: magento, layout

I need to set Search results page layout from 3 columns to 2-columns with leftbar.

but i don't get from where it can be change as I don't have xml files

Can anyone please help me to find this?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same thing in Magento go, so what I did was changed the blocks' position using theme editor and increased the width of main column using css.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `\app\design\frontend\default\your theme\layout/catalogsearch.xml`

**in line no 52:**

`<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>`

**change into:**

`<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>`

Comment: this is Magento Go , not Magento